Only cache non-dev depencies in Deno
In my Docker file,
I have docker cache main.ts
And I believe this caches my dev dependencies as well, since I haven't done anything special to differentiate it from any other kind of dependency.
In main.ts:
import { something } from 'dev_deps.ts';
import { isDev } from 'config.ts';

if (isDev) {
   something();
}

The isDev variable is only set when i run the dev task, and shouldn't be set when I do docker cache main.ts but I guess deno doesn't know this.
This is what config.ts looks like:
export const isDev = Deno.env.get('IS_DEV') === 'true';

Basically, I'm looking for an equivalent to how if I use import.meta.env.DEV in Vite in a condition, then I include some code only when I'm on dev server, and not on build.
